# Getting NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: 'Vacancy is not mapped' after moving common code to a Common Project in the same solution

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm creating another application which shares common entities so I moved the entities and mappings across to this new Common Project. I've changed the namespaces, added the project dependencies and added reference to this new common project but I'm getting the not mapped error. Is there steps I'm missing like adding a reference to it in the startup file or something?

ModelMapper

```
    private ISessionFactory ConfigureNHibernate() {
        var cfg = new Configuration();

        cfg.DataBaseIntegration(db => {
            db.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection");
            db.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
            db.BatchSize = 500;
            db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;

        var mapper = new ModelMapper();
        mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());
        cfg.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
        cfg.AddAssembly("MyProject.Common");

        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

Comment: what version of NHibernate are you using?  Are you using xml mapping files or mapping by code or fluent?

Comment: version 5.1.3 and using mapping by code

Comment: Are you adding your entity classes to your ModelMapper using AddMappings()?  Please add your your code that adds your mapping.

Comment: Yup, I've added the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the problem is here.

```
var mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.AddMappings(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes());
cfg.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
cfg.AddAssembly("MyProject.Common");
```

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() isn't going to be your new mapping project assembly.

I always create my domain model in a separate project and pass it in to the nhibernate initializer.

So I've got property on my NhibernateInitializer that takes the mapping assembly

```
private Assembly MappingAssembly
{
    get { return _mappingAssembly ?? (_mappingAssembly = Assembly.Load(_mappingAssemblyName)); }
}
```

That loads my mapping assembly.

Then when it time to configure them in my mapper the code is

```
    _mapper.AddMappings(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes());
```